Magnetic shielding, Superposition and "Guiding Field Lines"
Suppose a permanent magnet and an iron plate.
The iron plate is put into the vicinity of the permanent magnet. Hence the iron plate takes up some specific magnetization state. Behind the iron plate, it is said that the resultant magnetic field is reduced, hence acts as a magnetic shield.

Is it correct to say that the resulting magnetic stray field is simply the superposition of the magnetic field of the magnet and the magnetic field produced by the specific induced magnetization state of the plate?
Another explanation I read is that the iron plate "provides an easier path for the lines of flux to follow". Is this path then simply given by the resultant magnetic field direction of that superposition?

